# Can't deploy smart contract to hardhat network

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I set up a project with hardhat for an NFT app. I modify `hardhat.config.js` like this:

```
const { ALCHEMY_KEY, ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.8.0",
   defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
   networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rinkeby: {
      url: `https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_KEY}`,
      accounts: [`0x${ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    },
    // ethereum: {
    //   chainId: 1,
    //   url: `https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_KEY}`,
    //   accounts: [`0x${ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY}`]
    // },
  },
}
```

then I created a deploy script in the `scripts` folder with the `deploy` task

```
// scripts/deploy.js
const { task } = require("hardhat/config");
const { getAccount } = require("./helpers");

task("deploy", "Deploys the TokenV2.sol contract").setAction(async function (taskArguments, hre) {
    const tokenFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TokenV2", getAccount());
    const token = await tokenFactory.deploy();
    await token.deployed()
    console.log(`Contract deployed to address: ${token.address}`);
});
```

The problem it's when I run `npx hardhat deploy` it's shows this error in terminal: `Error: unsupported getDefaultProvider network (operation="getDefaultProvider", network="hardhat", code=NETWORK_ERROR, version=providers/5.5.3)` What I missed? I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I never used defaultNetwork in my works so I just had the following hardhat.config File and had no issues at all:

```
{
   "solidity":"0.8.4",
   "networks":{
      "rinkeby":{
         "url":"`https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_KEY}`",
         "accounts":[
            "`0x${ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY}`"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```